# How to use a list inside a string - flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to use an API that has a page parameter inside its call link. I want to know how can I use a list of integers to change the page number. I mean, I want to with a press of a button, page 1 changes to page 2, for example.
here is the list I want to use:

```
  List<int> pages = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
```

and this is the API link:

```
'http://www.moviesapi.ir/api/v1/movies?page=$pages'
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a variable named `index` and change it's value inside onPressed function of the button.

```
RaisedButton(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                    child: const Text('Submit Answer'),
                    color: Color(0xFFE08284),
                    elevation: 0.0,
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        submit = 1;
                      });
                    },
                  ),
http://www.moviesapi.ir/api/v1/movies?'page=${pages[index]}'
```

Comment: i used your code but it completely doesn't work now and it shows me null. the problem is with the index. when i removed that it works again and when i added a print, it show that page variable actually changes but the list doesn't.

Comment: Assign an initial value to `index`. Why are you trying to change the list?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's not too much necessary to define a list for it. work with an int will be easier.
In this example, we imagine you have a total of 12 pages.
The parameter "currerntPage" is what you should use in your get request.
'http://www.moviesapi.ir/api/v1/movies?page=$currentPage'

```
int currentPage = 1;
RaisedButton(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                    child: const Text('Submit Answer'),
                    color: Color(0xFFE08284),
                    elevation: 0.0,
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        currentPage++;
                        //currentPage--; if you want to go to previous page.
                      });
                    },
                  ),
```

And finally, you can use an if condition for showing or not showing next and previous buttons.
ex. : `if(currentPage<12) show next button`
`if(currentPage>1) show previous botton`

For the second case (using list of ints) you can use an index and do ++ or -- for pages[index].